# Could Amaterasu be used without a sharingan by sealing it like Jiraiya did?

Tags: naruto

This [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29526/17758) made me wonder: if you happened to have a scroll with Amaterasu sealed inside, could the seal on this scroll be released thus allowing you to use or spread Amaterasu without having a sharingan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a technique was never used in both anime and manga. However, judging from the way the sealing technique works, I suppose it can be used that way. The evidence for this is Tenten's usage of weaponries.

Tenten stores her weapons in a scroll by putting the said weapons on the open scroll and use a jutsu to seal it into the scroll.

Jiraiya stores the Amaterasu into a scroll too as shown in the question you mentioned.

Thus, as long as you use it within 7 days after its sealing, you can use it as a weapon. Although, to be on the safe side, you better throw the scroll away from you before you release it.

It is not clear whether time passes when being sealed in a paper scroll, thus it is not guaranteed that the scroll will work after the [7 days expiration time of Amaterasu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu#Overview).

Comment: Can you add the source for the 7 days of time for Amaterasu? I thought they were eternal (Till the users mangekyou deactivated)

Comment: It was mentioned in the question the asker referred to.