# Is it possible to seal Opponent Ninjutsu by using scroll?

Tags: naruto

After seeing naruto series we have seen different scroll of various sizes which are used to summon something or to do something related seal.

In Boruto: Naruto the movie, Konohamaru used Rasengan and sealed that in the scroll. So by that sealing Ninjutsu is possible.

So my question is that, is it possible for someone to seal enemy Ninjutsu on scroll.

For example

Naruto used Rasengan and throws it towards his enemy.
So is it possible for enemy to seal that Rasengan simply by opening scroll wide enough so that it can strike right through it and then get absorbed. I mean by that enemy can seal Rasengan again and again. So is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29526/why-did-itachis-amaterasu-not-burn-the-entire-inn

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be possible, since Konohamaru was able to seal his Rasengan. But I think you would need good timing if someone through a Rasengan at you and you wanted to seal it.

Comment: isn't that how Boruto's gauntlet basically works ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer it simply, **YES**, it is possible. However, only with mastery of sealing techniques can perform such ninjutsu and of course, with very precise timing.

In relation to Jiraiya who has been shown to seal Amaterasu, my theory is that the fourth *shared* his sealing skills to him which came from fourth's wife (Kushina) who is known to be skilled with [fūinjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/F%C5%ABinjutsu). An Uzumaki trait that earned them both respect and fear throughout the ninja world.

See [Uzumaki Clan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uzumaki_Clan)